# How to save editted data into core Data

Tags: ios, swift

I have created an application whereby a user can create a new account which consists of name, username and password. This is then added to a tableview. Once the user selects a specific cell and presses on the edit button, the user is displayed with a new viewcontroller which displays the loaded data in textfields.

So far I have gotten the viewcontroller to display the corresponding data of the selected tableview cell howerver How can I save this editted data onto my core data. Below is some code of how I saved the data to core date when a user creates a new account.

Code :

```
class AddAccount: UIViewController {
    let DataContext= (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    @IBAction func addAccount(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
            let newAccount = Account(context: DataContext)
            newAccount.name = nameuser.text
            newAccount.username= username.text
            newAccount.password= password.text

            (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()
    }
}
```

how can I create a similar method which will replace the existing data with the new data.

The variables used contain loaded data from a previous viewcontroller. My question is how can I be able to update the loaded cell details after the user edits them.

Edit:
I have managed to get the application to update changes after reading some information on Fetching records from CoreData. Thank you all for the help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Update the properties of the existing managed object and save the context

Comment: It is pretty simple. You have an instance of `Account` that you have retrieved from core data. Set,say, the `username` property of that object and save your core data context

Comment: Only if you create a new `Account` instance. If you update the jwtande then you are only updating. You need to understand that Core Data is an object persistence system, not a database. In memory objects are tied to persisted objects.

Comment: Fetch it, change it, save it.

Comment: [Fetching records from CoreData](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/FetchingObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH6-SW1) is very basic stuff. Assign an appropriate predicate to the request to get the particular record, update the attributes and save the context.

Comment: Could you please provide some more code? How are you getting the data for the table view from core data? Do you have an array of Account objects, which you simply fetch from core data? Or are you using a NSFetchedResultsController?

Comment: @JosefZoller code has been updated to show where I get my data from.  The loaded data depends on which cell was selected.

Comment: @vadian the example you have provided could you please tell me what " [EmployeeMO]" is in the line "  let fetchedEmployees = try moc.executeFetchRequest(employeesFetch) as! [EmployeeMO]"

Comment: These are the returned objects and `EmployeeMO` is the `NSManagedObject` subclass. A fetch returns always an array of objects. If no items could be found the array is empty. Please read the paragraph blow the code.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use a NSFetchedResultsController, whenever you have to show data from Core Data objects in a UITableView. There are many good tutorials, which describe exactly, what you need, for example [this one](https://cocoacasts.com/populate-a-table-view-with-nsfetchedresultscontroller-and-swift-3).